# When to use gigantic,large ,humongous and huge

Tags: vocabulary

When should I use gigantic, large ,humongous and huge

Comment: _Humungous/humongous_ is a jokey word; you would only use it in informal contexts.

Comment: The body of your question didn't contain any question at all.  So I've replaced it with the question from the title.  Please use a dictionary to look for the meaning of these words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, personally I would sort these into the following: large, huge, gigantic, humongous. The point is that each one would mean that it is bigger than the one before it.

This means that you would use one of these words based on the scale of what you're talking about. Or if you would like to exaggerate you could use humongous. However this is what I would do, have some sort of ordering of the words (order them how you would like in a sensible manner(meaning you could switch gigantic and humongous)).

Like I said the use of the words would be based on how big the object/animal/whatever is in question in a visual manner. So you would preferably use these words in accordance to that.